# Nomenclature for stationary states in the context of wave equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, waves, terminology, normal-modes

Consider the Schrodinger equation $i\partial_t u=-\Delta u.$ Special solutions of the form $$u(t,x)=u_k(x)e^{ikt}$$ have many names which I've seen used, such as stationary states, solitons, standing waves, etc. I am wondering what one would call such a solution to the wave equation $\partial_t^2u=\Delta u.$ If it matters, assume that the spatial domain is unbounded. I suppose one could call them a mode solution since they feature a particular Fourier mode.

Comment: “soliton” certain does not apply (this is not a travelling wave that keeps its shape, solution of a nonlinear differential equation), and it’s not a standing wave either since (as written) the wave is travelling in only one direction.

Comment: I would call it a Helmholtz eigenfunction.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero gotcha. Do you have any ideas on a standard name? I'm more interested in the technical mathematical phrasing, so I am not worried if it is somewhat inaccurate with the standard physical interpretation.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty that makes sense for how the question was phrased. However, that feels less robust, especially when considering operators who only equal the d'Alembertian at the principal level (you no longer get a simple Helmholtz equation when converting to a stationary problem).

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal standard for naming those solutions.

For mechanical or electromagnetic waves, a stationary *wave* is a wave that doesn't travel, typically of the form:

$$s(x,t)=A\cos(kx)\cos(\omega t)$$

However, in quantum mechanics, a stationary *state* is a wavefunction that has a probability amplitude that doesn't vary in time:

$$\psi(x,t)=\varphi(x)e^{-i\omega t}$$

You can have solutions like that for the d'Alembert equation, but their name would depend on the exact form of $u_k$.

- If $u_k$ is a real decreasing exponential, the wave is called *evanescent*.
- If $u_k$ is a real sine or cosine, the wave is called *standing*.
- If $u_k$ is a complex of the form $e^{ikx}$, the wave is called *traveling*.

If the spatial domain is bounded, then $k$ is quantized, and the solutions are called *modes*.

Comment: So, it would be inaccurate to use the phrase "stationary *state*." For evanescent, does $u_k$ need to be exponentially decreasing, or can it simply be spatially localized (e.g. in a Sobolev sense)? What if $u_k$ is complex-valued but localized in the manner described? Is there no longer a name which people use?

Comment: I used this expression only in a quantum context, where it has a very specific meaning. I also pointed out the discrepency that can exist between different parts of physics. "Stationary state" is an expression that I'm sure is in current use in quantum physics.